# Angular js-Sort table based on song duration and set default sort to title name

Tags: angularjs, html, sorting

How to sort a table displaying Song title, duration, artist by duration. I have used the following code in my HTML for sorting based on table header.
Also, how to set default sort to song title without using controller?

```
<thead><tr><th class="title" ng-click="orderByField='titlename'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Title</th>
<th class="artist" ng-click="orderByField='artist'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Artist</th>
<th class="duration" ng-click="orderByField='duration'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Duration</th></tr></thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<th ng-repeat="songs in songs | orderBy : orderByField : reverseSort>
 <td>{{songs.title}}</td>
 <td>{{songs.artist}}</td>
 <td>{{songs.duration}}</td>
</tr></tbody>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Sorting is working fine but default order is not set as title ascending. For Duration, the descending order is displayed as: 6:04:48, 4:09:25, 48:02, 46:18, 3:08:14, 2:33:51, 27:58 instead of 6:04:48, 4:09:25, 3:08:14, 2:33:51, 48:02, 46:18, 27:58. The same with ascending too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngInit to initialize sort criteria as you want:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-init="orderByField='title'; reverseSort=false"
        ng-repeat="songs in songs | orderBy : orderByField : reverseSort>

        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks. Its giving the reverse order. Is there a way out to sort ascending?

Comment: Inside `ng-init` you can initialize `reverseSort` as well.

Answer (score 0):

For default order, use  $scope.orderByField = 'titlename'; in the controller.